# Django MySQL group by day with timezone

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

Lets say I have a sale model:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    sale_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Now, with each sale sale_date get its value saved in UTC, so if I try to group and sum all the sales by day:

```
report = Sale.objects.extra({'day':"date(sale_date)"}).values('day').annotate(day_total=Sum('total'))
```

I get all wrong becouse I expect each day in a different timezone (UTC-6).

Is there a way to get the correct sums in a specific tiemezone? Im working with MySQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, this was a good challenge. I was able to test from PostGres, and I can confirm it is working. The MySQL code should be pretty close. However, there is a note on the [CONVERT_TZ documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz):

> To use named time zones such as **`MET`** or **`Europe/Moscow`**, the time zone tables must be properly set up. See [Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html), for instructions.

**MySQL** (using [CONVERT_TZ(dt, from_tz, to_tz)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz))

```
from_tz = 'UTC'
to_tz = 'Australia/ACT'
report = Sale.objects.extra(
    {
        'day': "date(CONVERT_TZ(sale_date, '{from_tz}', '{to_tz}'))".format(
            from_tz=from_tz,
            to_tz=to_tz
         )
    }
).values(
    'day'
).annotate(
    day_total=Sum('total')
)
```

**PostGres:** (using [AT TIME ZONE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT))

```
time_zone = 'Australia/ACT'
report = Sale.objects.extra(
    {'day': "date(sale_date) AT TIME ZONE '{0}'".format(time_zone)}
).values(
    'day'
).annotate(
    day_total=Sum('total')
)
```

Comment: Great, tanks!. As a side note, convert_tz also accepts the tz in offsets, `from_tz="+00:00"`, `to_tz="-06:00"`