# How to handle data grouping request by date across multiple time zones?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Here's the scenario. I'm using a MySQL/NodeJS/Sequelize stack on the server, and I have a request I want to perform.

There are anywhere from 1000-2000 entries that are retrieved from the request, but I don't need the full list of entries. I want the summary of the entries after they have been grouped by the day the entry was made, which condenses down to about 5-10 objects in an array.

If I group by day on the server, it may group them differently from the time zone of the client. And if I send it to the client, then I have to send 1-2k entries for analysis, but it will group them correctly.

How would you handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Use UTC timestamps for everything. For example open the Chrome console and enter this:

```
// Milliseconds since 1/1/1970
new Date().getTime()
1438263135084

// Human friendly without timezone
new Date().toISOString()
"2015-07-30T13:32:15.715Z"

// Human friendly with timezone
new Date().toString()
"Thu Jul 30 2015 09:32:21 GMT-0400 (EDT)"
```

All of these are the same (time since 1/1/1970), but simply formatted differently. Using either of the first two will allow you to send dates that can be interpreted and formatted correctly regardless of timezone.

Interesting reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've been using UTC for everything. The problem is that if I group it according to the day on the server, and then send it to the client, the server doesn't know when the day starts and ends for the client, so it will not group the dates correctly. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could convert the dates to the user's timezone [Django MySQL group by day with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182438/django-mysql-group-by-day-with-timezone) - but that of course requires you to know the user's timezone, and caching will be harder

In sequelize, it would be expressed something like

```
sequelize.fn('CONVERT_TZ', sequelize.col('date'), 'UTC', user_tz)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, thanks all for your suggestions on how to handle this. Ultimately, I resolved this issue by doing the following.

First, in the request from the client, I used the moment js method .utcOffset() to get the offset value.

Then, once I had the offset value, I included it into the API query as ?offset=(value here)

Finally, on the server side, I used this value to interpret the local timezone offset of the client, and then grouped all the data there, and send the formatted data back to the client. It resulted in a much faster, much, much smaller response query.

It was a fairly simple solution - I'm bugged it took me to long to come up with it.